# How can I Get value in tag with PHP simple HTML DOM parser

Tags: html, parsing, web, dom, screen-scraping

How can I to read data in tag url in the ?
I find in the manual and example but not found.

the tag like this in the below.

```
<tr role="cell" show-url="https://test.com"> </tr>
```

final I want = https://test.com

Please Help me. I can not see in the example.